# Handling event by data binding vs onClick assigned to a method in an Activity

Tags: android

Recently I've been reading aboout data binding in android. I get how this could be useful in updating the ui but what is the advantage in event handling? Assigning in XML `android:onClick` to a method in activity seems to me like a same thing to just with less code. 
When should I use which?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Assigning in XML android:onClick to a method in activity seems to me like a same thing to just with less code

First, `android:onClick` only works with an activity. Using data binding for event handling allows you to route that event to some other form of controller or presenter (e.g., a fragment).

Second, `android:onClick` only works with that event. Using data binding for event handling allows you to handle other sorts of events, replacing `OnLongClickListener`, `OnTouchListener`, etc.

Third, `android:onClick` only routes to a method, with a fixed list of arguments. Using data binding for event handling allows you to use Java 8-style lambda expressions to route to methods with a different roster of parameters, including variables that you may have injected into the layout (e.g., the `RecyclerView` position associated with this layout).

> When should I use which?

If you are bothering to use data binding, use it for event handling where practical. Data binding is useful for larger projects, and on those projects, you may find the features I listed to be useful.

If you are not using data binding in a project, use `android:onClick`.